# Efficiently scan classpath with spring for two packages

Tags: java, spring, classpath

How can I scan for components from two different packages with one sweep? For example if I wanted to scan from packages `com.google` and `com.apple` without having to do two scans? I could always scan for `com`, but it seems like that would not be very efficient. I am currently using Spring 4.2.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =  new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Controller.class));
Set<BeanDefinition> candidateComponents = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com");
```

Answer (score 2):

The *short* answer is that you *can't* scan multiple packages in one call but feel free to call `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents` multiple times. You should not fear about overhead here.

For instance `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` which is use internally by Spring has a `scan` method which takes a varargs of String (`String... basePackages`) and then loop on `findCandidateComponents`.

The *long* answer is that `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` delegates to a `ResourcePatternResolver` (in our case a `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`) to find all the `Resource's` from which we are going to read the metadata. To do so it uses a `PathMather` (in our case an `AntPathMatcher`) and a default pattern, appended to our `basePackage` : `**/*.class`.

If you wanted to have something more precise and do everything in one call you would have to write your own `ResourcePatternResolver`. If I were you, in the case of scanning 2 packages I would just make 2 calls of `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents` and forget about the little overhead. Of course if you are going to make a lot of calls and want to have the smallest overhead possible maybe writing your own `ResourcePatternResolver` could help you.